# How to call jQuery function from a different file

Tags: jquery

So i have 2 different files loaded with jquery where i need to call a function from 'file 1' in 'file 2' and i somehow keep getting an error, what am i doing wrong.

**Loading Order**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/messages/script.js') }}" defer></script> {{-- file 2 --}}
<script src="{{ asset('js/projects/createProject.js') }}" defer></script> {{-- file 1 --}}
```

**File 1** - js/projects/createProject.js

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    createFlashMessage("testStatus", "testMessage");
});
```

**File 2** - js/messages/script.js

```
//Start create Flash Message
function createFlashMessage(status, message) {
    $.ajax({
        url: API_URL + "/createflashmessage",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
        },
        data: { status: status, message: message },
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
}
//End create Flash Message
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: createFlashMessage is not defined
    at createProject.js:8
    at dispatch (app.js:12235)
    at elemData.handle (app.js:12039)
(anonymous) @ createProject.js:8
```

Comment: Which file is `createFlashMessage()` in? Is `createFlashMessage()` defined within scope of the location it's called from? For example if it's within a `document.ready` handler in a file it will not be accessible from any other file.

Comment: what happens if you remove all the asset stuf and just load with src="path/name"? btw {{-- file 2 --}} is no query. I assume you are using a framework like React or angular?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan added the filename for the codeblocks

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff asset() is a Laravel helper function, so not so much.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan these are the complete files. so the only handler is the `$(window).on("load", function() {}):`

Comment: @QuintenvandenHerik are you using ``document.ready`` wrapper in file ``js/messages/script.js``?

Comment: @RohitMittal no, this is the complete file.

Comment: can you check if both files are loading correctly? Open source code of the file and click on the file path, it should open file code if files are included correctly

Comment: @RohitMittal yes, it loads correctly. it can also fire console.log's and alert's.. so thats not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding this line of code at the closing tag of `createFlashMessage()` function:

```
window.createFlashMessage = createFlashMessage;
//End create Flash Message
```